# Firefox box-sizing + expanding div = missing padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I've been trying to solve this issue where I have an expanding div (as the content is added over time) with `box-sizing` and `padding`. The mentioned case works fine on ie and Chrome, but behaves weird on Firefox (33.0.2).

Here is the link

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mydPdV

Keep pressing the button. The button will send you to the end of the page via:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#container").scrollTop(99999999999999999);
});
```

After the page is filled, and scroll appears, you will see that for osme reason padding-bottom will stay out of the page - only on firefox! On Chrome and IE it works as it should.

It looks like Firefox is making some wrong calculation somhere? or does int not calculate padding at all, for the expanding/dynamic content? Am I missing a point?

I'm looking for a quickfix.

Comment: Why is body `position: fixed;`?

Comment: is it important at this point? removing the line doens't change anything.

Comment: It's just... unusual.

Comment: Any ideas on the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#button").click(
  function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newdiv = $("<div>");
    newdiv.text("Here is some dummy content");
    $('#content').append(newdiv);

    //$('#container').prop('scrollHeight');
    var sh = parseInt($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);
    //$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:sh},1000);
    $(window).scrollTop(sh);
    //return false
  }
);
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
#container{
  background: lightpink none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin:5%;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
#button{
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content div {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="button">PRESS ME</div>
</div>
```